# Htaccess ModRewrite for CodeIgniter with a parked/redirected domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I have this situation:

- hosting is located at maindomain.com
- othersite.com is parked to maindomain.com
- htaccess is used to redirect all requests for othersite.com to a subfolder: /site-othersite/
- I want to use CodeIgniter on othersite.com but there are some directories and files in othersite.com that I don't want to have the CodeIgniter redirection.
- home.php is my CodeIgniter main page.

I have tried to combine the usual ModRewrite that I use for my parked domains with what I found in the CodeIgniter wiki but am having trouble.

Example:
 I do not want othersite.com/demo/ or othersite.com/robots.txt to be handled by CodeIgniter. I have this:

```
# Redirect various urls to subfolders of the format: /site-thename/

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?othersite\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site-othersite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^robots\.txt

Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /site-othersite/home.php?/$1 [L]
```

Everything works fine for the CodeIgniter install. Except trying to get demo/ and robots.txt to be 'ouside' of CodeIgniter is not working.

And ModRewrite masters out there with suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I guess my confusion likes in understanding how the RewriteCond lines work. Do all of them have to be true for the rule to be executed? Also, how do I format the exceptions (the last 2 conditions). The second condition is required to prevent a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It needs to be handled in two rules:

```
# Redirect various urls to subfolders of the format: /site-thename/

RewriteEngine On

# Handle pages and directories that should not go through CodeIgniter.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?othersite\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site-othersite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/demo/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/robots.txt

Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /site-othersite/$1 [L]


# Handle CodeIgniter URLs.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?othersite\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site-othersite/

Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /site-othersite/home.php?/$1 [L]
```